# NER python - extracting nouns from raw data in a file?

Tags: python

I have the following code where I try to extract the noun words from the file:

```
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize
import re
from nltk.corpus import stopwords


fr = open('input.txt','r+')
fw = open('output.txt','a+')

for line in fr:
 line = line.lower() #converting from upper to lower case
 lines = ''.join([i for i in line if not i.isdigit()]) #removing numericals
 for word in lines.split():
  word=re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ' ',word)
  if word not in stopwords.words('english'):
   tokenized_word=word_tokenize(word)
   tokenized_word=nltk.pos_tag(tokenized_word)
   fw.write(str(tokenized_word))
   fw.write('\n')

fr.close()
fw.close()

fw = open('noun_output.txt','w+')

with open('output.txt','r+') as fr:
 for line in fr:
   word = [word for word,pos in line if pos =='NN']
   print word
```

when i run this code i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 29, in <module>
    word = [word for word,pos in line if pos =='NN']
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I did some trials on the word(like word[0][1] and splitting the word also) but couldn't resolve this problem.. please help!

Comment: `line` is just a string. How do you expect to unpack it into `word, pos`?

Comment: Why do you write everything to a file just to read it again? Is the idea that in reality the two parts of the program will happen at different times?

Comment: Anyway, if you need to encode multiple values into a string and then later separate them again, consider the `csv`, `json`, or `pickle` modules. Or if you want to get going extra fast, `import ast` and `word = [word for word,pos in ast.literal_eval(line) if pos =='NN']` should work for the way you've currently written to the file.

Comment: 1) Thats why i tried splitting it and reading. But, couldnt get through
2) Yes, actually i want to keep track of both the non noun words and others so that i can compare that is why i wrote to a file and then read from it again.
3) Replacing with the line which you suggested worked for me. Thanks..